# storm ui shows internal server error when started with Supervisor tool

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, apache-storm

I have installed supervisor to monitor Storm daemons. I am able to restart, stop, start etc. using the supevisorctl executable file. But, when I check the Storm UI (`ip:8080`), it shows internal server error. But, upon starting the daemons directly (using `bin/storm ui`, `bin/storm nimbus`, `bin/storm supervisor`), the UI shows up on port 8080 with no troubles. What might be the reason?